# Android checkLocationSettings never called in onResume

Tags: android, localization

I'm having a strange issue.

I was playing with the example of LocationServices, and I found out that if I try to call **LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings** in the *onResume* of the activity, the callback is never called.

I have modified the activity to start automatically the localization when the app starts, and the flow is:

- start the app;
- enable (if needed) the localization;
- put the app in background;
- disable the localization services;
- resume the app.

In the last step, I was expecting to see the dialog with a request to enable the localization, but this never happens.

The strange thing is that, when starting the app for the first time, it works flawlessly.

Somebody have experienced this?

EDIT:

```
public synchronized void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );

        Log.e(TAG, "check");

        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }
```

ResultCallback:

```
 @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        Log.e(TAG, status.toString());
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");
                    showDialogToCheckSettings(status);

                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                listener.impossibleToEnable();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Log.e(TAG, status.toString())** is never called in the onResume

Comment: can you please post the code for checking settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem.

The callback was not called because I forgot to call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` in onResume.